# Insertar datos a tablas relacionadas Mysql Java

Tags: java, mysql, insert

mi duda es la siguiente: Como se debe de insertar datos tanto a una tabla padre como a la hija.

Mi problema es que en mi proyecto Java tengo como clase padre a `Persona` y sus dos tablas hijas `Cliente` y `Empleado`.
La clase `Cliente` tiene tres datos extras a la clase padre que son `fechaAlta`, dos boleanos `estudiante` y `nuevoCliente`. Ahí es donde me surge el problema, a la hora de insertar solo una persona no tengo problema, y mi código es el siguiente:

```js
private static final String SQL_INSERT  = "INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellidos, telefono, calle, colonia, idTipoAcceso) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

private static final Conexion conn = Conexion.getInstance();

    @Override
    public boolean insert(Persona c) {
        PreparedStatement ps;

        try {
            ps = conn.getConn().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
            ps.setString(1, c.getNombre());
            ps.setString(2, c.getApellidos());
            ps.setString(3, c.getTelefono());
            ps.setString(4, c.getCalle());
            ps.setString(5, c.getColonia());
            ps.setInt(6, c.getTipoDeAcceso());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.cerrarConexion();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Pero para insertar desde la clase Cliente no se como se debe realizar la consulta hacia la BD, ya que debo de ingresar 7 datos a la tabla Padre `Persona` y los tres restantes a la tabla hija `Cliente` más el `idCliente` que se autogenera y el `idPersona` que no se de donde sacarlo.

Imagen de la BD: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme dado a entender, saludos!

Comment: Cuando tu insertas en la tabla `Persona`, automáticamente se debe de insertar a ambas tablas hijas? o van en un proceso diferente?

Comment: @Ricardo tenia pensado hacer un trigger en la tabla `Persona` para que dependiendo del `idTipoAcceso` me insertara en la tabla `Cliente` con el `idCliente` autogenerado y el `idPersona` jalado desde la tabla persona, pero quisiera poder llenar los otros 3 campos de la tabla `Cliente` en el mismo proceso, para no tener que hacer un proceso donde solicite el `idCliente` y realizar un update.

Comment: Y los otros 3 campos de donde los sacas?, el campo `fechaAlta` lo puedes llenar con un `GETDATE()`?, y me imagino que en tu trigger tendrás un proceso para saber si es `nuevoCliente` o no, y ya llenar ese campo, y el campo `estudiante` para que sirve?

Comment: @Ricardo Si, `fechaAlta` lo llenare con GETDATE(), y por en cuanto a `nuevoCliente` va por defecto true en cualquier INSERT a la tabla `Cliente`, y `estudiante` sirve para aplicar un descuento más adelante.
Imagina que entro al sistema como empleado, y hay un botón que dice `Agregar nuevo cliente`, al oprimir me pedirá todos los datos de `Persona` mas aparte los datos de `Cliente`, o en su caso si dan clic a `Agregar nuevo empleado` pedir datos de `Persona` más un usuario y contraseña para el empleado.

Comment: @Ricardo creo que no me estoy dando a entender, una disculpa. Lo que busco es pedir los datos para registrar un cliente sin que exista previamente en la tabla `Persona`, Así en la pantalla solicito todos los datos necesarios para crear la `Persona` mas los datos extra para la tabla `Cliente` y en base al `idPersona` generado insertar en la tabla `Persona` llenar la tabla `Cliente`.

Comment: Creo que la mejor manera de ver este tema, es que cada persona tena un identificador que lo defina solo a el/ella y a nadie mas, por ejemplo algún numero en su identificación oficial (INE para Mexico), o que tu les generes un identificador y que ellos lo mantengan presente. O en su caso, buscarlos por su nombre y apellidos (que no es optimo, por que podrían existir muchas personas con el mismo nombre). Así validas si existe, y si existe como persona, no lo insertas en la tabla `Persona`, no se si eso es lo que necesitas?.